# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) when trying to fetch data from json

Tags: angular6

Hello got this error when trying to get the json data

Service.ts file is showing error but it is compiling

Error:

Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'IEmployee[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)

Iemployee is the interface used

```js
export interface IEmployee {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  salary: number;
  dob: string;
}
```

employees.service.ts

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmployee } from './iEmployee';
import {  Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable ()
export class EmployeeService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
  return this.http.get('./employees.json')
   .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
  }
}
```

employees.component.ts

```js
import { IEmployee } from './iEmployee';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/employees/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css'] ,
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: IEmployee[] = null;
    constructor(private empService: EmployeeService) {
      // this.employees = this.empService.getEmployees();
    }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.empService.getEmployees()
    .subscribe((empdata) => this.employees = empdata);
  }

}
```

Even i have include Http module in app module.ts and after compiling only the headers of the table are visible and not the data

employees.component.html

```html
<table style = "width: 50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Date Of Birth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="employees">
    <tr *ngFor = "let emp of employees">
      <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.lastName | lowercase}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.salary | currency:'INR': true}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.dob | date | uppercase}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf = "employees.length==0">
      <td colspan="5">No data to Display</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the json file into assets folder which is present in src folder and I have assigned the path location to 'url' and used it as

private_url = '/assets/data/employees.json' ;

used the getEmployee method as

getEmployees(): Observable {

return this.http.get(this.private_url);
  }

now the values is being displayed